# Oracle SQL sequential group number assignment

Tags: sql, oracle, uniqueidentifier

I have a result set that for simplicity I will refer to as table "tab" of three columns: Category, Subcategory and Date, ordered by category and then date. This dataset is a grid and I wish to perform other processing on top of that grid. My problem is uniquely identifying (or sequentially labelling) groups within the dataset. The SQL below is what I am after (either GID1 or GID2 would do), based on the existence of the first 3 columns.
I have attempted group_id, grouping_id, rank, dense_rank and either missed a trick with one of these or am attempting something very awkward. It is not important what order the GID is, but is important that the group-number assignment is based on the data as ordered (category then date).

```
 CREATE TABLE Tab
        ("Category" varchar2(1), "SubCategory" varchar2(7), "Date" int, "GID1" int, "GID2" int);

    INSERT ALL 
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'bannana', 20120101, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'grape', 20120102, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'pear', 20120103, 1, 1)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'pear', 20120104, 1, 1)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'bannana', 20120105, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'pear', 20120106, 2, 2)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'pear', 20120107, 2, 2)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'apple', 20120108, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('A', 'pear', 20120109, 3, 3)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'apple', 20120101, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'bannana', 20120102, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'apple', 20120103, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'bannana', 20120104, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'pear', 20120105, 1, 4)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'pear', 20120106, 1, 4)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'pear', 20120107, 1, 4)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'pear', 20120108, 1, 4)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('B', 'pear', 20120109, 1, 4)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'grape', 20120101, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'grape', 20120102, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'apple', 20120103, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'bannana', 20120104, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'grape', 20120105, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'pear', 20120106, 1, 5)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'apple', 20120107, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'apple', 20120108, NULL, NULL)
        INTO Tab ("Category", "SubCategory", "Date", "GID1", "GID2")
             VALUES ('C', 'apple', 20120109, NULL, NULL)
    SELECT * FROM dual
    ;
```

Comment: this sounds like a LAG function.  check if the row before is in the same 'group', then set the current row to that same group number or increment it.

Comment: why have only "Pear" got GIDs? is that what you need, only the GID to apply to 1 given Subcategory?

Comment: DazzaL - good point, sorry I forgot to mention that, yes this GID concept only need apply to Pears.

Comment: Please show us the expected output based on your sample data

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name - listed above as SQL with the GID1 and GID2 columns being the expected result, just bolted onto the original table.

Comment: Randy - Thank you for guiding me to the LAG and LEAD functions - they actually help with my original query to get to this result set also. The problem is I still do not know how to assign a different number to each group of 'pears' within or across the category.

Comment: CupOfTea I provided the answer to that below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok if its just pears then:

```
SQL> select "Category", "SubCategory", "Date",
  2         case
  3           when "SubCategory" = 'pear'
  4           then
  5             count(rn) over (partition by "Category" order by "Date") else null
  6         end GID1 ,
  7         case
  8           when "SubCategory" = 'pear'
  9           then
 10             count(rn) over ( order by "Category", "Date") else null
 11         end GID2
 12    from (select "Category", "SubCategory", "Date", lag("SubCategory") over (partition by "Category" order by "Date"),
 13                                    case
 14                                      when lag("SubCategory") over (partition by "Category" order by "Date") != "SubCategory"
 15                                      and "SubCategory" = 'pear'
 16                                       then 1
 17                                      when row_number() over (partition by "Category" order by "Date") = 1 and "SubCategory" = 'pear' then 1
 18                                      else null
 19                                    end rn
 20                               from tab)
 21   order by 1, 3;

Category   SubCate       Date       GID1       GID2
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A          bannana   20120101
A          grape     20120102
A          pear      20120103          1          1
A          pear      20120104          1          1
A          bannana   20120105
A          pear      20120106          2          2
A          pear      20120107          2          2
A          apple     20120108
A          pear      20120109          3          3
B          apple     20120101
B          bannana   20120102
B          apple     20120103
B          bannana   20120104
B          pear      20120105          1          4
B          pear      20120106          1          4
B          pear      20120107          1          4
B          pear      20120108          1          4
B          pear      20120109          1          4
C          grape     20120101
C          grape     20120102
C          apple     20120103
C          bannana   20120104
C          grape     20120105
C          pear      20120106          1          5
C          apple     20120107
C          apple     20120108
C          apple     20120109
```

to break this down.

we look at the prior row ordered by "Date" (for each "Category") and see if it was a different "SubCategory" and also that the current cateogry = pear. if so we tag the row with a "1" (irrelevant what we use, just NON NULL).

```
lag("SubCategory") over (partition by "Category" order by "Date") != "SubCategory" 
 and "SubCategory" = 'pear'
```

also for the first row we assign the same. this give us:

```
Category   SubCate       Date LAG("SU         RN
---------- ------- ---------- ------- ----------
A          bannana   20120101
A          grape     20120102 bannana
A          pear      20120103 grape            1
A          pear      20120104 pear
A          bannana   20120105 pear
A          pear      20120106 bannana          1
A          pear      20120107 pear
A          apple     20120108 pear
A          pear      20120109 apple            1
B          apple     20120101
B          bannana   20120102 apple
B          apple     20120103 bannana
B          bannana   20120104 apple
B          pear      20120105 bannana          1
B          pear      20120106 pear
B          pear      20120107 pear
B          pear      20120108 pear
B          pear      20120109 pear
C          grape     20120101
C          grape     20120102 grape
C          apple     20120103 grape
C          bannana   20120104 apple
C          grape     20120105 bannana
C          pear      20120106 grape            1
C          apple     20120107 pear
C          apple     20120108 apple
C          apple     20120109 apple
```

now, simply we count() the not null "RN" values ordering again on Date (per category for GID1, and not for GID2[gid2 we order by it too!). which is these lines:
`count(rn) over (partition by "Category" order by "Date")` (GID1)

and 
`count(rn) over ( order by "Category", "Date")` (GID2)

Comment: Brilliantly helpful Dazzal, this one has been bugging me and I have leant quite a bit from this post. Thank you for succinctly explaining how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Never thought it could be done with count. Brilliant. 
Starting from version 11r2 this could be done by making use of recursive hierarchical query.

```
with r as ( 
  select "Category"
    , "SubCategory"
    , "Date"
    , row_number() over (partition by "SubCategory" order by "Category", "Date") rn
  from tab
)
, fwd ( "Category", "SubCategory", "Date", rn, GID1, GID2) as (
  select "Category"
    , "SubCategory"
    , "Date"
    , rn
    , 1
    , 1
  from r
  where rn = 1
  union all 
  select nxt."Category"
    , nxt."SubCategory"
    , nxt."Date"
    , nxt.rn
    , decode( nxt."Category"
      , prev."Category", decode( nxt."Date"
        , prev."Date" + 1, prev.gid1
        , prev.gid1 + 1 
      )
      , 1
    ) as gid1
    , decode( nxt."Date"
      , prev."Date" + 1, prev.gid2
      , prev.gid2 + 1 
    ) as gid2
  from fwd prev
    , r nxt
  where prev.rn + 1= nxt.rn
    and prev."SubCategory" = nxt."SubCategory"
)
select "Category"
  , "SubCategory"
  , "Date"
  , decode( "SubCategory", 'pear', GID1, null ) as gid1
  , decode( "SubCategory", 'pear', GID2, null ) as gid2
from fwd
order by "Category", "Date";
```

It produces the same result

```
Category SubCategory       Date       GID1       GID2
-------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A        bannana       20120101                       
A        grape         20120102                       
A        pear          20120103          1          1 
A        pear          20120104          1          1 
A        bannana       20120105                       
A        pear          20120106          2          2 
A        pear          20120107          2          2 
A        apple         20120108                       
A        pear          20120109          3          3 
B        apple         20120101                       
B        bannana       20120102                       
B        apple         20120103                       
B        bannana       20120104                       
B        pear          20120105          1          4 
B        pear          20120106          1          4 
B        pear          20120107          1          4 
B        pear          20120108          1          4 
B        pear          20120109          1          4 
C        grape         20120101                       
C        grape         20120102                       
C        apple         20120103                       
C        bannana       20120104                       
C        grape         20120105                       
C        pear          20120106          1          5 
C        apple         20120107                       
C        apple         20120108                       
C        apple         20120109
```

and can be a little more self explanatory.

Also it produces right GID1 and GID2 numbers for all other SubCategories not only 'pear' if you remove `decode` from the final select.

It's up to cost comparison to choose between this variant and the one provided by @DazzaL